# Store object to database

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve binary stream object from Collections, to be stored in a Database table as varbinary. How is it possible to store to database using ASP.Net with C# ? I am using SQL Server 2008. What will be the process to store to database including connection process ?

Comment: Hang on...  From your questions this morning, it seems that you want to read files from a folder, convert them to binary streams and then put the streams into your database...  You might have better luck if you tell us what you are trying to achieve with the whole process, and then we can help you to come up with a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to do that ? that is not what a database is suited for. Perhaps you should move the files to the filesystem of the database server and store [meta-data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) about the files in the actual database.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this would be to serialize the objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28VS.71%29.aspx